# How to set image path using thymeleaf with spring boot from the system local folder

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Iam working with spring boot and I want to display an image from local directory of my system in html page but it is not working.

My system os is windows

This is the configuration class.

```
@Configuration
public class ImageConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

            registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("file :D:\\aigsImages/").setCachePeriod(0);
            System.out.println("Image configuration initialized");
        }
    }
```

Image tag of html page

```
<img th:src="@{'/images/' + /loginbg.jpg}" alt="no image" class="img-fluid" />
```

Comment: there is a blank between file and :

Comment: Simon Martinelli thanks from your comment.. I removed the space but it still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image tag is wrong.

You have to set:

```
<img th:src="@{/images/loginbg.jpg}" alt="no image" class="img-fluid" />
```